# Vertical alignment of foreign language in table

Tags: tables, luatex, hebrew, vertical-spacing

I'm trying to have two texts parallel in a tabular environment.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[nil, main=german, bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Ezra SIL}

\usepackage{array}
% ========================================================
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{>{%
    \leavevmode\raggedleft\arraybackslash% <- fixes vertical alignment issue
    \selectlanguage{hebrew}}p{2in}p{2in}}%
      אַ֥שְֽׁרֵי הָאִ֗ישׁ אֲשֶׁ֤ר לֹ֥א הָלַךְ֮ בַּעֲצַ֪ת רְשָׁ֫עִ֥ים 
      וּבְדֶ֣רֶ חַ֭טָּאִים לֹ֥א עָמָ֑ד וּבְמוֹשַׁ֥ב לֵ֝צִ֗ים לֹ֣א יָשָֽׁב׃
    &%
      Wohl dem, der nicht wandelt im Rat der Gottlosen
      noch tritt auf den Weg der Sünder noch sitzt, da die Spötter sitzen
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the texts are not on the same baselines.

(I'm compiling with LuaLaTeX because I could not get the vertical alignment issue fixed in XeLaTeX; see my comment, try for yourself.)

How can I achieve having the right text vertically spaced like the left one? Is there a way to have p-columns that have fixed-height lines, which I would be able to adjust? I want the baselines to match (like in the first line) and the rest to fall where it falls.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should clarify that I also wanted to have the basic letter height to match the uppercase latin letters, but they already match, so I didn't need to scale the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ta’amim of the Hebrew text don’t fit into the `\baselineskip` distance, and also your fonts aren’t scaled to the same height.  You can fix the former with `setspace` and the latter with `Scale=MatchUppercase`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[german, bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}

%% Taamey Ashkenaz is free at http://culmus.sourceforge.net/taamim/index.html
%% Like Ezra SIL, it is based on Hebrew Bibles printed circa 1900.  It comes
%% in two weights (of which Bold is more like the original) and in a slanted
%% shape (although some  Israelis prefer a left-to-right slant, matching the
%% Latin script).
\defaultfontfeatures[TaameyAshkenaz]{
    UprightFont = *-Medium ,
    BoldFont = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont = *-MediumOblique ,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldOblique ,
    Extension = .ttf
  }

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0]{TeX Gyre Schola}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}
          {TaameyAshkenaz}

\usepackage{array}


% ========================================================
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{>{%
    \leavevmode\raggedleft\arraybackslash% <- fixes vertical alignment issue
    \selectlanguage{hebrew}}p{2in}p{2in}}%
      אַ֥שְֽׁרֵי הָאִ֗ישׁ אֲשֶׁ֤ר לֹ֥א הָלַךְ֮ בַּעֲצַ֪ת רְשָׁ֫עִ֥ים 
      וּבְדֶ֣רֶ חַ֭טָּאִים לֹ֥א עָמָ֑ד וּבְמוֹשַׁ֥ב לֵ֝צִ֗ים לֹ֣א יָשָֽׁב׃
    &%
      Wohl dem, der nicht wandelt im Rat der Gottlosen
      noch tritt auf den Weg der Sünder noch sitzt, da die Spötter sitzen
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Taamey Ashkenaz / TeX Gyre Schola sample]

I took the liberty of changing the fonts you used.  There are several good alternatives [at the Culmus Project](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/taamim/index.html) and [the OpenSiddur project](https://opensiddur.org/help/fonts/).

Instead of hand-rolling a table, you might want to use the `paracol` package.  Here, I’ve set up an environment that switches to the appropriate language for each column, turns off hyphenation in the Hebrew column (since we don’t want to introduce any word breaks or marks into the Biblical text that were not originally there), makes the translation wider than the original Hebrew so as to better match the height, and narrows the left and right margins so that the Hebrew doesn’t overflow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[german, bidi=basic]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip, paracol, xspace}

\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}

%% Taamey Ashkenaz is free at http://culmus.sourceforge.net/taamim/index.html
%% Like Ezra SIL, it is based on Hebrew Bibles printed circa 1900.  It comes
%% in two weights (of which Bold is more like the original) and in a slanted
%% shape (although some  Israelis prefer a left-to-right slant, matching the
%% Latin script).
\defaultfontfeatures[TaameyAshkenaz]{
    UprightFont = *-Medium ,
    BoldFont = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont = *-MediumOblique ,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldOblique ,
    Extension = .ttf
  }

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0]{TeX Gyre Schola}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{TaameyAshkenaz}

\newcommand\obverses[2]{%
  \begin{leftcolumn*}\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}%
  \righthyphenmin=62%
  \lefthyphenmin=62%
  \emergencystretch=3em% Don’t want to hyphenate or introduce any
  % additional marks into the Biblical text.
  {#1}%
  \end{otherlanguage}\end{leftcolumn*}%
  \begin{rightcolumn}\begin{otherlanguage}{german}%
  {#2}%
  \end{otherlanguage}\end{rightcolumn}%
}

%% Set your conventions for translating the Divine Name here.
\newcommand\HERRN{\textsc{Herrn}\xspace}

% ========================================================
\begin{document}
  \columnratio{0.33}
  \columnsep=1cm
  \begin{paracol}{2}
    \obverses{
      אַ֥שְֽׁרֵי הָאִ֗ישׁ אֲשֶׁ֤ר לֹ֥א הָלַךְ֮ בַּעֲצַ֪ת רְשָׁ֫עִ֥ים 
      וּבְדֶ֣רֶ חַ֭טָּאִים לֹ֥א עָמָ֑ד וּבְמוֹשַׁ֥ב לֵ֝צִ֗ים לֹ֣א יָשָֽׁב׃
    }
    { Wohl dem, der nicht wandelt im Rat der Gottlosen
      noch tritt auf den Weg der Sünder noch sitzt, da die Spötter sitzen
    }
    \obverses{
כִּ֤י אִ֥ם בְּתוֹרַ֥ת יְהוָ֗ה חֶ֫פְצ֥וֹ וּֽבְתוֹרָת֥וֹ יֶהְגֶּ֗ה יוֹמָ֥ם וָלָֽיְלָה׃
    }
    { sondern hat Lust zum Gesetz des \HERRN und redet von seinem
      Gesetz Tag und Nacht!
    }
    \obverses{
וְֽהָיָ֗ה כְּעֵץ֮ שָׁת֪וּל עַֽל־פַּלְגֵ֫י מָ֥יִם אֲשֶׁ֤ר פִּרְי֨וֹ ׀ יִתֵּ֬ן בְּעִתּ֗וֹ וְעָלֵ֥הוּ לֹֽא־יִבּ֑וֹל וְכֹ֖ל אֲשֶׁר־יַעֲשֶׂ֣ה יַצְלִֽיחַ׃ 
    }
    { Der ist wie ein Baum, gepflanzt an den Wasserbächen, der seine Frucht
      bringt zu seiner Zeit, und seine Blätter verwelken nicht; und was er
      macht, das gerät wohl.
    }
    \obverses{
לֹא־כֵ֥ן הָרְשָׁעִ֑ים כִּ֥י אִם־כַּ֝מֹּ֗ץ אֲ‍ֽשֶׁר־תִּדְּפֶ֥נּוּ רֽוּחַ׃ 
    }
    { Aber so sind die Gottlosen nicht, sondern wie Spreu, die der Wind
      verstreut.
    }
  \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: Taamey Ashkenaz/TeX Gyre Schola sample]

Since there are several different conventions for translating the Divine Name, I added a macro `\HERRN` so you can choose how to typeset it.  It’s particularly easy to do a case-sensitive search-and-replace if your translation says HERRN.  I went with small caps.  You might also want `\HERR`, `\LORD`, etc.

Add the option `[import, onchar=ids fonts]` to `\babelprovide` if you want to be able to type in Hebrew anywhere in the document and have it auto-detect the language.  Change the settings of `geometry` and set `\pagestyle{empty}` if you really wanted a standalone PDF.

Comment: The accents not fitting is fine. Thanks for reminding me of `\onehalfspacing`, as I must have forgotten about it. I'm now using `\begin{spacing}{1.33}` with the original font, which seems as close as I can get it.

Comment: @mklein Right, but that’s why the baseline was being expanded: to make room for the cantillation marks.