# 2 column on different languages

Tags: minipage, two-column

How can I make a text in 2 column but in different languages. I need a left column on page in English and right in Russian, the text is quite big (not one page). If I'm using

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
text
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
text
\end{minipage}
```

It doesn't go to the next page[image]

I've tried to use paracol, but in such case I've got problem with word hyphenation in English
[image]

Comment: Is it for a translation?

Comment: Yes, that's for translation

Comment: In this case there are at least three packages for that: parallel, parcol and parcolumns.

Comment: I’ve done several examples on this site before, [such as this one.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580716/vertical-alignment-of-foreign-language-in-table/580725#580725) Does that help?

Comment: I've used a parasol and add \sloppy in preamble. Now it works great